# Escape reserve characters when searching for OU by name

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have written a search utility to search for AD objects. It is working perfectly.

the problem arises when any OU name have a reserve character in its name for example ','

and before searching I use to replace ',' with '\,' and it works fine.

but I check only for ',' not for other reserve characters.

Is there any way that I can escape those characters also, before searching?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "@" to escape special characters.
Example:

```
string strSpecialChar = @"this,is'with&special?chars";
```

Comment: That is for escaping within C#. The problem here is LDAP special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape all these by prefixing with a "\".